# Convert txt to array in powershell

Tags: database, powershell

I have a powershell script and a txt database with different number of elements per line.

My txt file is list.txt:

```
"10345","doomsday","life","hope","run","stone"
"10346","ride","latest","metal"
```

My powershell script search.ps1:

```
#Get file path
$path = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

$search = @()
Get-Content -LiteralPath "$path\list.txt" | ForEach-Object {
$search += $_
}
```

So, how to convert each line as a element of array? As this:

```
$search = @(("10345","doomsday","life","hope","run","stone"),("10346","ride","latest","metal"))
```

To operate as:

```
echo $search[0][0]
```

Comment: Should the quotes be removed from the items? In other words; should `$search[0][0]` return `"10345"` or just `10345`?

Comment: Thanks for attention. I edited my txt and I used only commas to separate itens. With this original script below you must replace the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a concise PSv4+ solution:

```
$search = (Get-Content -LiteralPath $path\list.txt).ForEach({ , ($_ -split ',') })
```

- The `.ForEach()` method operates on each line read from the input file by `Get-Content`.
- `$_ -split ','` splits each line into an array of strings by separator `,`
- `, (...)` wraps this array in an aux. single-item array to ensure that the array is effectively output as a whole, resulting in an array of arrays as the overall output.

  - Note: Strictly speaking, the `.ForEach()` method outputs a `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]` collection rather than a regular PowerShell array (`[object[]]`), but for all practical purposes the two types act the same.

Note: The `.ForEach()` *method* was chosen as a faster alternative to a pipeline with the `ForEach-Object` (`%`) *cmdlet*.
Note that the `.ForEach()` method requires storing the input collection in memory as a whole first.

---

A faster and more memory-efficient, though perhaps slightly obscure alternative is to use a `switch` statement with the `-file` option:

```
$search = switch -file $path\list.txt { default { , ($_ -split ',') } }
```

- `switch -file` processes each line of the specified file.
- Since each line should be processed, only a `default` branch is used, in which the desired splitting is performed.

Comment: Since OP appears to be a newer user, I wrote answer in a way that can be easily run in a debugger line-by-line.  Between these 2 answers, people should get a good grasp on this scenario.

Comment: *Slightly* obscure ...? o_O

Comment: I hope so, @KoryGill. The reason I wrote my own answer is that, even though I think yours is helpful, I wanted to show a more concise alternative,  notably one that avoids the use of `+=` to inefficiently build an array (you may have done that solely to facilitate debugging, but I suggest noting that this approach should be avoided in real code) and focuses just on the solution.

Comment: yes, unless it's some small structure, I avoid `+=` on an `@()` and will always use ArrayList/etc.  thanks @mklement0.

Comment: Come on, things like that are making PowerShell look like Perl.

Comment: @KoryGill: An ArrayList is preferable, but a simpler and more efficient alternative is to treat a `foreach` statement as an _expression_ whose output you can collect in an (array) variable: `[array] $arr = foreach(...) { ... }`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Good old Perl - I've always had a soft spot for it. Kidding aside: point taken; spreading the statement across multiple lines might help some, but there's inherent complexity in the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-split`.  A code snippet you can debug in ISE or VSCode below.

```
$x1 = @'
"10345","doomsday","life","hope","run","stone"
"10346","ride","latest","metal"
'@

$data = $x1 -split "`r`n"

$data.Count

$data[0] -split ","

$arr = @()
foreach ($row in $data)
{
    $arr += ,($row -split ",")
}

"arr"
$arr

"0,3"
$arr[0][3]

"1,3"
$arr[1][3]
```

So you can split each line in your file returned from Get-Content and add it to your new array which lets you reference how you wanted...

There are other ways you can use your data depending on your needs.

Comment: Note that `Get-Content` already does the ``-split "`r`n"`` part, so that split is only necessary when processing a multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want each item quoted, you might consider to ***not*** using the [`-Split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) but just evaluating each line with the [`Invoke-Expression` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6) or using a more secure [`[ScriptBlock]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-6) for this:

```
$Search = Get-Content ".\list.txt" | ForEach-Object {,@(&([ScriptBlock]::Create($_)))}
```